# Submit form values using controller and model in magento admin module

Tags: php, model-view-controller, magento

I am building an admin module and need to process a form but am having troubles getting the variables to POST and am just redirected to the dashboard.  The form looks like this :

```
<form name="notes" action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("foo/index/processnotes/");?>"  method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="another_form_key" value="<? echo $this->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

I am doing it that way because the secure keys are turned on for admin.  It gives me a url like :

```
foo/index/processnotes/key/4745f5fbb9c168778958d5d4a4c2c0ef/
```

In the controller I have:

```
public function processnotesAction(){       
    $model = Mage::getModel('foo/process');
    // I am not sure how I am supposed to send $_POST values here
    }
```

and in `Package/foo/Model/Process.php`

I would hope to be able to process the POST variables from my form in here but I can not see what is wrong and I am just sent to dashboard.

```
<?php
class Package_foo_Model_Process extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
        public function noteProcess() {     
            $test = $_POST['myValue'];
            echo $test;
     }
}
```

### Update

After reading the answers I wanted to add a bit more of what my real code is doing and how I am using $_POST.  I was setting up a simple example to just get the form to post but realizing there are probably many things I am doing wrong in Magento.

```
  $query="INSERT INTO `notes_value` ( `color`, `the_id`, `the_value` ) VALUES ";
 $sku = $_POST['color'];
array_pop($_POST);
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) {
        $values[] = "('$sku', '$id', '$value')";
}   
$query .= implode(', ', $values) . ';';
```

The dream is I could `$resource->getConnection('core_write');` to actually insert this into the database but feeling less optimistic with how it is going so far.

Answer (score 9):

Usually when you are getting redirected to the dashboard because your key is not recognised. I normally would use the following syntax

```
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

Also, I would be inclined to disable admin keys to verify whether that is your issue.

Next, **never, ever** use `$_POST` with Magento, all variables are accessible (cleanly and securely). POST information is accessible globally (not just in a controller), however you can still set variables in your model from the controller like this:

```
public function processnotesAction(){       
  $model = Mage::getSingleton('foo/process');
  $model->setData('postdata', $this->getRequest()->getPost() );
}
```

Then accessing them from your model with:

```
$this->getData();
$this->getMyPostedField();
```

Or you could just use this in your Model

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost();
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('myargument');
```

`getPost` can also take a parameter to fetch a single POST value - but it does not get GET values. `getParam` will return both GET and POST values alike.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question a bit to show the crazy way I am trying to get all of these values (from radio buttons) and then INSERT them.  So are you saying from the example in my question I would add what you have to the controller, and then in the model have something like `$sku=Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('color');` ?

Comment: You use either method I recommended. Also, using `$resource->getConnection('core_write');` is not best practice for inserting into the DB - you should really create your own MySQL4 resource in your extension.

Answer (score 3):

Request params are accessible via the request object, `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http`. Example usage:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$params = $request->getParams();
$someParam = $request->getParam('param_key');
// or $params = $request->getPost();
```

You then need to set the data on your model and call `$model->save()`.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am pretty lost with this stuff. Can you please elaborate some and maybe provide an example?  Otherwise it is just so abstract to me right now.

Comment: Why would you call `$model->save()`? Surely using a Model singleton would mitigate that requirement, and the need for the OP to have to write/use a `save()` or `load()` method?

Answer (score 0):

If your controller extends ActionController, then the preDispatch() function is the one responsible for redirecting you to the dashboard (and checking for valid form key..).

I suggest you put Mage::log debug info into ActionController's preDispatch function, that might help identify what's going on?

I was gonna post a comment, but don't have high enough reputation.

(maybe update your post or comment on the answer that helped you, to see how you solved it (or not))